# Are local variables stored in memory or on the stack in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design

Are local variables stored in memory or on the stack in Solidity?

If memory, is the memory freed after the function returns?

Answer (score 10):

For value types (booleans, integers, addresses ...) it's memory. For complex types (arrays, structs, maps) the default location depends on the context and can be [overridden](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#data-location) by `memory` and `storage` keywords.

Whenever there is a need to perform some computation on the variable (adding, multiplying, negating ...) the variable will be moved from the memory/storage to the stack (along with other  variables needed for the operation), the result will be put back to the memory/storage.

After returning from a function the free memory pointer will be updated so the unused memory can be reused. The return value of a function can also be located in the memory or storage.

Answer (score 1):

The EVM has a stack-based architecture. It has a volatile memory where items are stored as byte arrays. The size of each stack item is 256-bit and the stack has a maximum size of 1024.

The memory is freed but your program will stop running if the new stack size is greater than 1024.

White paper - https://ethereum.org/whitepaper/

Yellow paper - https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf

Comment: Are you sure memory is freed? I've seen that memory only expands (never shrinks). If you mean by "freed" that the memory can be reused for other variables, then I agree.

Answer (score 0):

All simple local data variables(booleans, integers, addresses ...) will store in stack. Some complex data variables(Like arrays, string, struct) by default will save in storage. Thats a reason Remix or solidity compiler will throw warning to us.